# Sticky Cloth Simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to animate a girl dancing. At the beginning when she raises her arm though, her skirt sticks to her arms and follows with them...Here are some shots of what it looks like:

[image]

(Frame 28)

[image]

(Frame 79)

I've made sure that all of the stickiness and friction settings are turned all the way down to 0 on the collision settings (the body). However, just in case, I'll attach screenshots of the collision and cloth settings:

[image]

(Collision settings applied to the body)

[image]

(Cloth settings on the skirt)

Did I miss something? Or is there something else I need to modify so that the cloth simulation works properly?

Here is the .blend file (Dropbox): https://www.dropbox.com/s/xhq0qzef5z8j10r/KC_JEWEL%20-%20Copy.blend?dl=0

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi @Shayana, can you provide your .blend file? We can more easily assist that way. https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/including-a-blend-file

Comment: @ComputerScientist Sure thing! I've added it as a Dropbox link.

Comment: Maybe attach a force field to her arms?

Comment: @EricXue Thanks, I could try that.